# deploying a java webapp using netbeans

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans, tomcat7, ussd

I am trying to develop a ussd application based on the MChoice library [here](http://code.google.com/p/mchoice-applications/wiki/JavaGuide).Everything is working out ok but am having trouble running the application.Am using ubuntu 12.04,netbeans and tomcat7.Integration of netbeans and tomcat is ok since the server is even started during deployment.Here is the output in the netbeans console.

```
ant -f /home/mungaih/NetBeansProjects/ussdHello -Dbrowser.context=/home/mungaih/NetBeansProjects/ussdHello -DforceRedeploy=false -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
In-place deployment at /home/mungaih/NetBeansProjects/ussdHello/build/web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext4764512515208631777.xml&path=/ussdHello
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext4764512515208631777.xml&path=/ussdHello
/home/mungaih/NetBeansProjects/ussdHello/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1050: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 36 seconds)
```

Where could i be going wrong?

Comment: "See the server log for details." what does server log says? (you can see them from netbeans, under services-> servers-> tomcat (right click) view server output)